# Why are objects not valid as a React child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I hope anyone can help me! I cant render my object in the right way.

**My JSON:**

```
{"status":"Entregado","_id":"5f490dd9b3f5192230a8f536","products":[{"_id":"5f44eaa1cf215b305449e216","name":"Reto Gratuito Medita Healing","price":0,"createdAt":"2020-08-25T10:40:33.845Z","updatedAt":"2020-08-25T10:40:33.845Z","__v":0,"count":1}],"details":"dimebag_666","client_email":"jobroman83@gmail.com","state":"CDMX","address":"acueducto","zip":"16200","client_id":"5f2ac527543c3835d028337c","amount":0,"createdAt":"2020-08-28T13:59:53.129Z","updatedAt":"2020-09-07T09:03:39.117Z","__v":0}
```

I rendered almost all the component with this code:

```
const SingleOrder = (props) => {

    const token = getCookie('token')  //// <-- right one
    const Id = getCookie('token')  



    const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [statusValues, setStatusValues] = useState([])

    const loadSingleOrder = orderId => {
        read(orderId,token).then( data => {
            if (data.error){
                setError(data.error)
            } else {
                setOrder(data)
            }
        })
    }

    const loadStatusValues = () => {
        getStatusValues(Id, token).then(data => {
            if (data.error){
                console.log(data.error)
            } else{
                setStatusValues(data)
            }
        })
    }

    const handleStatusChange = (e, orderId) => {
        // console.log('update order status')
        updateOrderStatus(Id, token ,orderId, e.target.value).then(
            data => {
                if (data.error){
                    console.log('status update failed')
                } else {
                    // setRun(!run)
                    loadSingleOrder(orderId)
                    console.log('changed')
                    alert('Has Cambiado el estatus')
                }
            }
        )
    }

    const showStatus = (order) => {
        return (
            <div className='form-group'>
            <h5 className='mark mb-4'>Estatus: {order.status}</h5>
            <select className='form-control' 
                    onChange={(e) => handleStatusChange(e, order._id)}>
                <option>Actualizar estado de orden</option>
                {statusValues.map((status, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={status}>{status}</option>
                ) )}

            </select>
        </div>
        )
    }

    


    const showInput = (key, value) => {
        return (
            <div className="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <div className="input-group-text">{key}</div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" value={value} className="form-control" readOnly/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    useEffect (() => {
        const orderId = props.match.params.orderId
        loadSingleOrder(orderId)
        loadStatusValues()
    },[props])

    const showOrderList = () => {
        return (
            <div className="card mr-2 mt-2 mb-5">
                <h5 className="mb-1 mt-2 text-center bg-primary"  style={{color:'red'}}>Numero de Orden: {order._id}</h5>
                <ul className="list-group">
                                    <li className='list-group-item'>
                                    {/* {o.status} */}
                                        {showStatus(order)}
                                    </li>
                                    <li className='list-group-item'>ID cliente: {order.client_id} </li>   
                                    <li className="list-group-item">Télefono: {order.client_phone}</li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item"  style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}> Cuenta de <i class="fab fa-instagram"/>  vinculada al Taller: {order.details}</li>
                                    <li className="list-group-item">E-mail: {order.client_email}</li>
                                    <li className='list-group-item'>Total de la orden: ${order.amount}</li>
                                    <li className='list-group-item' style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Comprado el dia:{" "}
                                            {moment(order.createdAt).locale('es').format('LL')}
                                        </li>
                                    <li className='list-group-item'>Dirección : {order.address}</li>
                                    <li className='list-group-item'>Estado : {order.state}</li>
                                    <li className='list-group-item'>Código Postal: {order.zip}</li>
                                    
                           if a put this code the problem is --> "TypeError: order.products is undefined"     {order.products.map((p, pIndex) => (
                                        <div className='' key={pIndex} style={{padding:'20px', border:'1px solid #e6c4ba'}}
                                        
                                        >
                                            {showInput('Nombre del producto:', p.name)} 
                                            {/* {showInput('Precio del producto $:', p.price)}  
                                            {showInput('Cantidad pedida del producto:', p.count)}  
                                            {showInput('ID del producto:', p._id)}    */}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                              if i only put this i recived --> {order.products}

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name, price, createdAt, updatedAt, __v, count}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
                                </ul>
            
            </div>
        )
    }



    return(
        <Layout>
            <div className='container'>
                {/* {showOrderList()} */}
                {JSON.stringify(order)}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )

}
```

But when i want to render the products inside of my object i cant Render them, its because of that i receiving the message :

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {_id, name, price, createdAt, updatedAt, __v, count}). If you meant to
> render a collection of children, use an array instead.

`{order.products}`

I have to render this in the right way, I tried with `map` etc.. I'm always getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map()` like this:

```js
<ul>
{order?.products.map(item => (
    <>
      <li>{item.name}</li>
      <li>{item.price}</li>
      <li>{new Date(item.createdAt)}</li>
      <li>{new Date(item.updatedAt)}</li>
    </>
  )
}
</ul>
```

you can also include the rest of the object items like `id` or `count` if necessary.

using `<> </>` tags are a short way of `<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>` respectively.

Comment: hello! when i used this , react send me an error: "order.products is undefined"

Comment: try `order?.products.map...`

Comment: what means the ' ?'

Comment: @David_roman Could you please mark my answer as resolved then?
`?.` means `optional chaining` when you try to access property that doesn't exists it will return `undefined` instead of an error, if it exists in will return its value itself, you can read more info about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining